# without alert page is not redirecting via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to redirect my page to the url which is coming in my variable but its not working without alert.

if i put alert then its redirecting otherwise not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
    var newurl = 'http://www.xyz.com/' + $(this).attr('href');
      //$(this).attr(newurl,'href');
      window.location.href = newurl;
       alert(newurl);
    });
});
```

thanx in advance

anchor tag

```
<a href="includes/footer.jsp">new url</a>
```

Comment: You are not preventing the default action, which is following the URL in the link. This will take precedence over setting the URL manually (because the default action happens later and  therefore overwrites the changes). See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/. Why it works with `alert`, I don't know. It might cancel the default action somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `preventDefault` to event handler, to prevent following the URL in the link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var newurl = 'http://www.xyz.com/' + $(this).attr("href");
      window.location.href = newurl;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function (event) {
        var newurl = 'http://www.xyz.com/' + $(this).attr('href');
        window.location.href = newurl;
        event.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

You need to prevent the default event from propagating by using `preventDefault()`.  The browser is redirecting to the `href` before jquery has a chance to change it.  By using the alert, you are delaying the browser redirect and hence it appears to work.